# Android filtered video from camera

Tags: android, camera

I can't understand how to display filtered video from camera on Android ***correctly***...

I wrote for sdk-8, so I've used the scheme below:

1. Camera.setPreviewDisplay(**null**); // use null surface holder to identify the fact that I don't want to see raw camera preview.
2. Camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer() + Camera.addCallbackBuffer() // to get camera data, modify it and draw on my GLSurfaceView

And this scheme is wonderful works on 2.2.* androids... and I had been happy, until didn't try application on 4.* =) my callback function for receive frame data doesn't called at all!

According documentation, I shouldn't use **null** as argument for **setPreviewDisplay**... without surface instance, video stream will not run... but if I give him surface he will start drawing camera raw preview on that surface....

The question is: How can I correctly draw filtered camera video by my self?!